# Generate thread dump from java code

Tags: java, multithreading, jenkins, thread-dump

I have the following method which overrides the default sorter in Jenkins:

```
@Override
public void sortBuildableItems(List<Queue.BuildableItem> items) {
    logBuildQueue(items, "BEFORE");
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    Future future =  executorService.submit(new Runnable() {
        @Override public void run() {
            items.sort(CustomSorter::compare);
        }
    });
    try {
        future.get(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e) {
        LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, "[INTERRUPTED EXCEPTION] Message:" + e.getMessage() + " StackTrace: " + Arrays.toString(e.getStackTrace()));
        setDefaultSorter();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (ExecutionException e) {
        LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, "[EXECUTION EXCEPTION] Message:" + e.getMessage() + " StackTrace: " + Arrays.toString(e.getStackTrace()));
        setDefaultSorter();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (TimeoutException e) {
        LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, "[TIMEOUT EXCEPTION] Sorting the items took more then 2 seconds, Message:" + e.getMessage() + " StackTrace: " + Arrays.toString(e.getStackTrace()));
        setDefaultSorter();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    logBuildQueue(items, "AFTER");
}
```

I'm looking to print all I can get my hands on in case an exception occurs, and I was wondering if there's any way to get a thread dump pushed to the logs, since the error message might be absent.

Comment: https://blog.fastthread.io/2016/06/06/how-to-take-thread-dumps-7-options/ and https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13150_01/jrockit_jvm/jrockit/geninfo/diagnos/using_threaddumps.html

Comment: Just wondering, what is the use of submitting a `Future` if you do a `get()` immediately after?

Comment: I want to introduce a timeout of 2 seconds on the call of items.sort(CustomSorter::compare). If that line takes more than 2 seconds I catch the TimeoutException and setDefaultSorter();

Comment: @fantaghirocco the first link solves it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    public void  dumpThreadDump() {
    ThreadMXBean threadMxBean = ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean();
    for (ThreadInfo ti : threadMxBean.dumpAllThreads(true, true)) {
        System.out.print(ti.toString());
    }
}
```

This seems to be a nice way of programatically obtaining a thread dump from the current application.